Choosing appropriate Reference Variables for Symbolic Analysis
So I have been building a compiler and currently I am in the process of doing some symbolic analysis with affine expressions this can be utilized in several optimizations.
An example it gives in the book is
for(m = 10; m < 20; m++){
  x = m * 3; 
  A[x] = 0;
}

gets converted to
x = 27;
for(m = 10; m < 20; m++){
   x = x + 3;
   A[x] = 0;
}

the above optimization is strength reduction the multiplication was gotten rid of and replaced with addition
My question has to do with the analysis that makes this transformation possible. I need to pass symbolic maps as the data flow value. Or in my case sets of Tuples with the structure
(String, Reference Expression). Where the String is a definition Name, And Reference expression is a expression that is made up of reference variables.
My Question is specifically how to determine which variables are reference variables and which are not. In my case I am dealing with loops so the Index variable should be a reference variable clearly and that is easy for me to see in person. But what if the variable isn't part of a loop index but would be a good reference variable. More specifically how do I get the computer to understand that variable m is an index of a loop. Because all of this is converted to Ir before running any of the analysis. The only thing I can think of is to run another Analysis before hand that is similar to Liveliness Analysis but on the upward pass just add good reference variables to the gen sets.
The book I am reading doesn't mention anything about another pass. Idk any advice would be helpful.
